# When would u-substitution be used in the numerator?

Tags: integration, substitution

For most integrals I have came across, *u* is almost always substituted in the denominator. However, I came across the following integral: $$\int\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x}dx$$

I intuitively thought that $1+x$ would be substituted, but according to the solutions, *u* had to be ${\sqrt{x}}$.

My question is, how do I distinguish between when *u* has to be substituted in the denominator versus the numerator?

Comment: Computing indefinite integrals isn't the most cut and dry thing. For more difficult integrals like the one above, it's kinda like a puzzle. You have to try out things until you make the breakthrough. Basically, I'm saying that for non-obvious integrals like the one above, you never know what substitution is the right one until you try them

Comment: Cases also exists where the substitution only has to be a part of either the numerator or the denominator (and where substitution is usable and there is no fraction involved). You have to try various substitutions unti you find one that works. In doing so you might notice that some substituions make certain things (dis)appear, and depending on whether that's good (i.e. makes the integral easier) or bad, that can affect your next guest. Doing a lot of this to build an intuition is the only way (I know of) to make this easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$u=1+x$ is fine. Your integral changes to

$$\int \dfrac{\sqrt{u-1}}{u} du$$

Here you find yourself in need of another substitution though, for example $u=\sec^2t$. Note that this makes $t=\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{x+1})$.

This gives

$$\int \dfrac{\tan t}{\sec^2 t}\cdot 2\sec^2 t\tan t \ dt=2\int \tan^2 t \ dt=2(\tan t-t) + c$$

Back substituting gives the answer

$$2\tan(\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{x+1}))-2\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{x+1})+c$$

This can be simplified further using trigonometric properties if desired.

Answer (score 2):

$$I= \int \frac{\sqrt{x} dx}{1+x}$$
Your substitution should yield integral of $u$ which is doable. Hereif you
take $x=u^2 \implies dx=2udu$,then
$$I=\int\frac{2u^2du}{1+u^2}=2 \int \left( 1-\frac{1}{1+u^2}\right)du=2
[u-\tan^{-1} u]=2[\sqrt{x}-\tan^{-1} \sqrt{x}]+C.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hyperbolic substitution**

Letting $x=\sinh ^2 \theta,$ then $d x=2 \sinh \theta \cosh \theta d \theta$ transforms the integral to
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &=\int \frac{\sinh \theta}{1+\sinh ^2 \theta} \cdot 2 \sinh \theta \cos \theta d \theta \\
&=2 \int \frac{\sinh ^2 \theta}{\operatorname{coch}_\theta} d \theta \\
&=2 \int \frac{\cosh ^2 \theta-1}{\cosh \theta} d \theta \\
&=2 \int(\cosh \theta-\operatorname{sech} \theta) d \theta \\
&=2\left[\sinh \theta-\tan ^{-1}(\sinh \theta)\right]+C\\&= 2\left(\sqrt{x}-\tan ^{-1} \sqrt{x}\right)+C
\end{aligned}
$$